# What is UndefvarError?

Tags: compiler-errors, julia

I am working master's course.
I have a program file that run in version julia-0.3.6.
And I upgraded the Julia program to version 0.5.0 in linux however the file do not run.

```
f=open("../info.dat","r")
order,nt,nx,ny,nshot,srcy=int(split(readline(f)[1:6])
```

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: int not defined
```

what is the problem?

Comment: ``int is not defined``. In other words, you've spelt it incorrectly or used the incorrect case. Looks like you're after ``Int`` if I'm reading the manual correctly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `int` function has been deprecated in Julia v0.4 and was removed in Julia v0.5, so an `UndefVarError` occurs when you try to use it. (Note that functions are first-class objects in Julia, and so are bound to names just like any other variables are. When an unbound name is used, an `UndefVarError` is thrown.) The correct way to write your code in Julia v0.5 is

```
f = open("../info.dat", "r")
order,nt,nx,ny,nshot,srcy = [parse(Int, x) for x in split(readline(f))]
```

However, this code is not great, because it does not close `f` afterward. I would recommend

```
order, nt, nx, ny, nshot, srcy = open("../info.dat") do f
    [parse(Int, x) for x in split(readline(f))]
end
```